# Table to 9^9 query header to table again

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, transpose, substitution

I have this [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rmPT8hBdoZkX_B-OhH3CrHmavPPYePAkov85cenlokA/copy) with a table

I want to go from the table to nested header and back to table again from the nested ranges header.

I tried using split transpose to expand the table, but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: There's no way to distinguish between blank spaces in a single cell from blank spaces that separate the different columns. Would you consider having a symbol different from blank spaces as a separator in your QUERY?

Comment: Yes if its in one cell its OK

Comment: answer updated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your dataset it is not possible to go from A12 to A16. you will need to attach some unique symbols first and only then you can cut it with split fx

in A12 use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1:E9), " ", "♦"),,9^9))
```

in A16 use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A12:E12), " ")), "♦", " "))
```

or full:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(
 TRIM(A1:E9), " ", "♦"),,9^9)), " ")), "♦", " "))
```

Comment: Can someone please explain the 9^9 parameter used as header in google query function, what does it do and how does it work?

Comment: @WesleyJeftha sure, 9^9 is just a big number with no further significance. it can be any big number you wish for like 12243504153 or 251245, 888^5, 100000, etc. it doesn't matter whats the value. the only rule is that it needs to be equal or higher than all rows in the sheet (if your sheet has 10 rows in total the number can be 11). in such manner, you can think of this parameter as "get all rows"

Comment: Cheers bro! makes sense now